# Member must have length less than or equal to 40 - aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `PHP` app which works well in `Heroku`, I have since uploaded the files to try on `amazon-web-services` utilising `Elastic Beanstalk`.

When I click the URL, I am getting a 403 Forbidden error.

When I use the console to open the application instead, I am getting a message that says:

```
ERROR: ServiceError - 1 validation error detected: Value '[http://heatmapclydebank-env.csjaqh9cyk.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/]' at 'environmentNames' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 40, Member must have length greater than or equal to 4]
```

I can't find much about this error online. What is this actually telling me and how do I resolve this in AWS.

NB: It is a custom app, vanilla php, no frameworks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to evaluate when you don't specify even the name of the app (Is it open source or a custom app? If custom, what framework/libraries does it use?).

Anyway, it looks like your app forces a 4-40 character limit on an "environment name", which is prefilled with the loooong beanstalk URI.

Can't tell more without knowing at least some bascis about the app you're trying to run.

Comment: its a custom app, vanilla php, no frameworks, AWS gave it the Url in the first instance

Comment: I have no experience with Elastic Beanstalk whatsoever (only PHP, that's why thought the issue is in the PHP app). It looks like you have the configuration wrong somehow. Looking here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateEnvironment.html under `EnvironmentName` I can see the same char limit as in your error message. So it looks to me like you're using the whole long URL as an environment name. I suppose changing the environment name to something like "development" should fix that.